# Найти всех юзеров, которые имеют все перечисленные интересы

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть табличка users с полями id, name, age, email, date; табличка interests с полями id, name; табличка users_interests с полями user_id и interest_id. Поля user_id и interest_id связаны внешними ключами с полем users.id и interests.id.

Допустим, у нас есть форма для поиска людей по интересам. У меня есть список интересов в виде чекбоксов. Я отмечаю интересующие меня и начинаю поиск.

Нужно найти всех юзеров, которые имеют ВСЕ выбранные интересы.

Есть небольшая заминка. Я знаю как это сделать с помощью HAVING, но мне надо сделать без его использования. Подскажите, пожалуйста, ваши идеи.

Comment: А почему такое требование "без having" ? Вы конечно можете сделать так же как обычно с having, т.е. сгруппировать и получить количество, потому обернуть этот запрос в еще один (просто поместить его подзапросом в from) и проверить то же самое количество во внешнем запросе в where. Но вот насколько это будет лучше странного требования "без having" сложно сказать, потому что по факту то же самое

Comment: @Mike, просто мне надо несколько реализаций данной задачи, как бы это бредово не звучало. Чисто в интересах обучения. Вот с HAVING я и сама сообразила, надо еще варианты, если есть)

Comment: ну тогда вот то что сказал выше, проверить то же кол-во во внешнем запросе. или написать пачку exists с подзапросами на каждый интерес или столько же join сколько интересов. в общем остальные варианты конечно для обучения можно, только в жизни их лучше не использовать, они громоздкие и тормозные

Comment: @Mike, спасибо за советы) Мне один знакомый говорил, что пачка JOINов намного быстрее одного HAVING. Можете сказать, пожалуйста, свое мнение?

Comment: А это от данных зависит. Если например есть в списке очень редкие интересы, то join с таким условием вполне может оказаться быстрее, если оптимизатор догадается начать именно с той записи, т.е. сначала подобрать десяток пользователей с этим редким интересом и потом работать только с ними. А если у нас тысячи записей с каждым из интересов, то один раз пройти и посчитать значительно быстрее, чем (тысячи раз) * (кол-во-join) искать записи в приклеиваемых таблицах. Еще есть такой подход как merge index но выигрыш он дает редко

Comment: Здесь рассмотрено несколько способов: http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_relational_division.html